# How to open an executable from node js using open library

Tags: node.js

I was trying to use the open library to try and open an executable from node js but I'm running into an issue. See their documentation states that I have to specify the name of the app I'm trying to open then call `open.openApp()` but when I try to do that It doesn't open the executable at all plus the weird part I don't understand is if I don't assign a specific path to the executable location how can it find the app accurately. How can I open an executable with open library properly? And also do you recommend to even use it? If not what other method do you prefer?

**Note:** when I specify a URL to open on a specific browser, as I included below in my code, It works and opens the Url

Library documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

```js
(async() => {
  //this works opens google.com in chrome
  await open('https://google.com', {
    app: 'google chrome'
  });
  //this 2 aren't working
  await open.openApp(open.apps.chrome);
  await open.openApp('word');
})();
```

Comment: Hi, i think there is a misunderstanding: the package expose the `openApp` method, then inside the implementation will use the correct method for the correspondent OS. The example you posted works flawlessy.

Comment: does it open word for you for example? @MatteoPHRE

Comment: To open Word you have to use `await open("WINWORD")`, where WINWORD is the name of the executable.

Comment: how do you find the correct names of the exe? Is there a database or so I can take a look at? @MatteoPHRE

Comment: Also ```await open("WINWORD")``` is not opening word for me either. @MatteoPHRE

Comment: No i don't know if there are any list or database (doing a fast search i found this https://www.devhut.net/ms-office-executable-file-versions/) but you can also search where is located your MSOffice folder and then you can find the executable names. And if WINWORD doesn't work, you should try to set the full path to the executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241134/discussion-between-matteophre-and-seriously).